# 70 TB Cassandra migration to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

We have a 70TB cluster which has around 200 Keyspaces, and planning to move this to AWS. Few approaches which we are thinking

- Replace the node in one of cluster with a Node in AWS, and do that one by one for all nodes
- Create a new Cluster in AWS, Bulk Copy each key space and do the dual write to both the clusters, and cutover during downtime.

Any other better ways to do this? Could we use the AWS as a new DC and change one keyspace at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for a live migration you can use a hybrid cloud model and create a new DC in AWS.  This is probably the best approach if you want to migrate data without downtime and you can do this keyspace-by-keyspace to manage the I/O streaming.

This blog article by Alain Rodriguez on [Cassandra Data Center Switch](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/02/26/data-center-switch.html) provides a walk though of how to do this in great detail.

Using AWS Snowball is a faster and cheaper approach if downtime is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS as a new cluster. But you  need to be careful. Not all cassandra sstable can talk each other, so you need to verify the compatibility between sstables. Another issue is that you can cause some high load in your "old" cluster.

So i high recomend that you start with this parameters very low to test the powerful of your cluster and the AWS cluster:

```
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec (Default 16)
stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec (Default 200)
```

Bootstrap a new AWS node inside your actual cluster is not a good idea, because you will tell to cassandra redistributed the keys between the cluster each time that you bootstrap a new node and you will stay without "plan b" if anything wrong.

Another good solution is make a separeted cluster(without connect them) in AWS and move the data with SPARK. Just move the data without transform is very simple and you are "on the control" of the process  .